# Unstable NIntegrate result vs plot

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, special-functions, interpolation

Here I have a $\Psi$ function with a few arguments:
[image]

```
\[CapitalPsi][r1_, r2_, Nsize_, c_, eta_] := \[CapitalPsi][r2, r1, Nsize, c, eta] = \!\( \*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(n2 = 1\), \(Nsize\)]\(( \*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(n1 = 
        1\), \(n2\)]\(c[\([n1]\)]\)[\([n2]\)]  \*SqrtBox[ FractionBox[\(64  \*SuperscriptBox[\((eta)\), \(6\)]\), \(n1 \((n1 + 1)\) n2 \((n2 + 
            1)\)\)]]  \*SuperscriptBox[\(E\), \(\(-eta\)*\((r1 + r2)\)\)] \((LaguerreL[
           n1 - 1, 2, 2*eta*r1] LaguerreL[n2 - 1, 2, 2*eta*r2] + 
         LaguerreL[n2 - 1, 2, 2*eta*r1] LaguerreL[n1 - 1, 2, 
           2*eta*r2])\))\)\);
```

$c$ is the coefficient that is stored as a 47x47 matrix and can be download [here](https://ufile.io/x2y8k)

Here comes the interesting thing:

First get rid of the dummy dimension

```
c = Import["~/Downloads/c.mat"];
c = ArrayReshape[c, Dimensions[c]~DeleteCases~1];
```

Then plot vs integrate:

```
Plot[\[CapitalPsi][r1, 0.01, 47, c, 0.675314001427934]^2*r1*r1, {r1,40,50}]
```

[image]

```
NIntegrate[\[CapitalPsi][r1, 0.01, 47, c, 0.675314001427934]^2*r1*
  r1, {r1, 40, 50}]
```

> NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly;
>   suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is
>   0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small. >>
>
> NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy
>   after 9 recursive bisections in r1 near {r1} = {44.8631}. NIntegrate
>   obtained 2420.258935677104`and 347.10349104798587` for the integral
>   and error estimates. >>

```
= 2420.26
```

But how could it be? The plot seems smooth but it seems there is a divergence in the integral that the singular point at 44.8631 contribute to the majority of the integral (2420.258935677104 out of 2420.26)

**Update:**

To make it easier for people to get the coefficient matrix $c$, you can also do it in this way:

```
URLSave["https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=\1lZeEfZ1I2UmVaHJ_hRAZqtgkipI8P6su", "c.mat"]
c = Import["c.mat"]
c = ArrayReshape[c, Dimensions[c]~DeleteCases~1];
```

Comment: We could better help you if you posted code the we could evaluate. That is, if you gave use an actual value for `c`, not an expression we can't evaluate.

Comment: @m_goldberg The c value can be downloaded from the link in the question. Maybe I should have made it more noticeable.

Comment: It would be nice if there were included an `Import[]` command that downloaded the data. Not sure if ufile.io supports that. Here are some discussions on Meta about ways to make large amounts of data or code available on SE: [(1351)](http://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1351), [(1520)](http://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1520), [(2145)](http://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2145). (I like pastebin, because I can inspect the code easily in a browser before deciding whether to download it into *Mathematica*.)

Comment: I used Google Drive so it will never expire, which I think is better than other choices. Please let me know if you have any trouble downloading the data.

Comment: The `URLSave` did not work for me, so I copied the data here: `c = ToExpression@Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/jMWZasFN", "Text"];`, which also doesn't expire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an interesting question, even though it has the feel of an edge-case.  The problem arises because the accuracy of the function evaluation depends on whether the function

```
c = ToExpression@Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/jMWZasFN", "Text"]; (* another source *)
Ψ[r1, 1/100, 47, SetPrecision[c, 100], 0.675314001427934`100]^2*r1*r1
```

is evaluated with a symbolic `r1` or a numeric `r1`.  With a numeric `r1` only a few digits are lost due to rounding error.  However if the function is evaluated with a symbolic `r1` and then a numeric value is substituted for `r1`, more digits are lost than one has at machine precision (or double precision, which is about 16 digits).

`Plot` evaluates its function after `r1` has been assigned a value (effectively with `Block` according to the docs).  Here we evaluate the function with a symbolic `r1` before passing it to plot, which results in a catastrophic loss of accuracy.  The plot is very different than the OP's.

```
Block[{f},
 f[r1_?NumericQ] = Ψ[r1, 0.01, 47, c, 0.675314001427934]^2*r1*r1;
 Plot[f[r1], {r1, 40, 50}, MaxRecursion -> 3]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`NIntegrate` on the other hand evaluates the integrand before constructing a `NumericFunction` to use in computing the integral, which is disastrous in the OP's case.  Below we prevent the symbolic evaluation of the integrand with [?NumericQ](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037) protection and [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html).  `NIntegrate` evaluates accurately without problems.

```
Block[{f},
 f[r1_?NumericQ] := Ψ[r1, 0.01, 47, c, 0.675314001427934]^2*r1*r1;
 NIntegrate[f[r1], {r1, 40, 50}]
 ]
(*  0.0338579  *)
```

We can examine the precision loss by computing the function two ways with 100-digit arbitrary-precision numbers and calculating the precision loss.  Evaluating with symbolic `r1` results in almost 22 digits lost, much more than machine precision.  The results are completely useless.  However, evaluating with a numeric `r1` results in under three digits lost, which leaves around 13 accurate digits, sufficient to compute a numerical integral to 8-digit accuracy.

```
(* evaluate with symbolic r1 first *)
(Ψ[r1, 1/100, 47, SetPrecision[c, 100], 0.675314001427934`100]^2*r1*r1 /. r1 -> 45.`100 // 
   Precision) - 100
(*  -21.9455  *)

(* assign r1 a numeric value before evaluation *)
Block[{r1 = 45.`100},
  Ψ[r1, 1/100, 47, SetPrecision[c, 100], 0.675314001427934`100]^2*r1*r1 // Precision
  ] - 100
(*  -2.75681  *)
```

Comment: Happy to learn from your insight +1

Comment: @JoséAntonioDíazNavas Your function interpolation made me wonder how the value of `NIntegrate` could become so large, so +1 to you, too. (It turns out that `FunctionInterpolation` evaluates its argument the same way as `Plot`.)

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your function to be integrated, it has multiplications of coefficients of high value by others of very, very low one. Arithmetic problems could arise. Maybe some expert could add light to this.

I propose a workaround based on `FunctionInterpolation` of your integrand in the range of interest:

```
if = FunctionInterpolation[\[CapitalPsi][r1, 0.01, 47, c, 0.675314001427934]^2*r1*r1, 
     {r1, 40, 50}];
Plot[\[CapitalPsi][r1, 0.01, 47, c, 0.675314001427934]^2*r1*r1 - if[r1], {r1, 40, 50}]
```

[image]

The difference with the original is low. So integrate it:

```
NIntegrate[if[r1], {r1, 40, 50}]

(* 0.0338579 *)
```

which seems to be a reasonable result.

Comment: Thanks! This is amazing because I assumed interpolation would not be a good approximation at all, but I was wrong!

Comment: Well, your function is quite smooth in the range of integration, so why not to make a try?  :))